# Garbage collection methods in c# application

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, garbage-collection

I have this question :

[image: question]

I can't understand why the second [choice](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.suppressfinalize(v=vs.110).aspx) is the answer . I mean other methods ( [KeepAlive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.keepalive(v=vs.110).aspx) and [CancelFullGCNotification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.cancelfullgcnotification(v=vs.110).aspx)) will prevent system to call the finalizer.

1. What are the differences between the four methods?
2. In which cases, we have to use it?

Comment: KeepAlive prevents collection until the line of code where KeepAlive is called. CancelFullGCNotification has nothing to do with it.

Comment: BTW if you read the links you posted, it explains both of them and how they are different than `SuppressFinalize`.

Comment: `PublicizeFinalize` is my favorite method.  Because it doesn't exist.

Comment: @Zer0 At least you can imagine its implementation :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The KeepAlive will only ***delay*** the finalizer being called on a class (by making the object live longer and not having it be eligible for finalization) and `CancelFullGCNotification` has nothing to do with finalizing.

Only `SuppressFinialize` will ***prevent*** the finalizer from running on a class.

Comment: Reworded for better clarity

Answer (score 3):

The use of SuppressFinalizer is only necessary when you have coded a finalizer.  Most of the time you would not need to suppress.  Anyway, `B` is correct answer and the only way to prevent the destructor/finalize method from being called.

Answer (score 1):

More importantly... the finalizer should rarely ever be used and delays garbage collection by itself.

It's there to clean up unmanaged resources and this is the pattern typically used:

```
public class SomeClass : IDisposable
{
    private bool disposed;

    //disposing is true if you're disposing managed resources
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                //Dispose managed resources
            }
            //Dispose unmanaged resources
            disposed = true;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    ~SomeClass()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Honestly, that pattern is pretty bad too (even if it is the reference one from Microsoft). You should never have managed and unmanaged items in the same class. If you have unmanaged items they should have managed wrappers around them ([SafeHandles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle(v=vs.100).aspx)). See the VERY good blog post by Stephen Cleary "[IDisposable: What Your Mother Never Told You About Resource Deallocation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29534/IDisposable-What-Your-Mother-Never-Told-You-About)"

Comment: @ScottChamberlain There's nothing wrong with this pattern and a vast number of .NET internals use it.  Anyways, the point I'm making is you rarely should have a finalizer and it delays garbage collection.  And having a finalizer when you _don't_ have unmanaged resources is bad.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Ironic enough, the `WaitHandle` class (the core of synchronization) uses this same pattern.  From the source: `public void Dispose() { Dispose(true); GC.SuppressFinalize(this); }`